# Where to put a separate business logic class or classes in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am designing a new application and plan to use CakePHP 3.  Typically when designing an application on top of a PHP MVC framework (CakePHP, CodeIgniter) I have implemented a separate set of classes that represents the business layer or service layer (depending on what words you like to use).  Thus, the stack:

-- Views

-- Controllers [really just another part of the views; code-behind from C# land]

-- Business layer [where business logic goes, because business logic spans multiple domain objects and isn't appropriate for a single Model/DAO]

-- Models [aka Data Access Objects]

...with domain objects (now "Entities" in Cake PHP 3) traversing between the layers.

I see that Cake PHP 3 still lacks any concept of a business layer in the default architecture, which is disappointing but hardly insurmountable.  But after all that, my question is actually rather pedestrian.  It is:  Where do I put MyBusinessLayer.php?  In Cake PHP 2 I would have put it in app/Lib, and loaded it up with

```
App::Import('Lib', 'MyBusinessLayer');
```

**What is the equivalent in CakePHP 3, and how do I load it?  I realize I could just stick it any old place and require_once(), but I wonder if there is a way that is more consistent with Cake PHP standards.**  This question could just as easily apply to a ten-line utility class, but in my case it applies to the business layer.

Comment: Both good answers, and thank you.  The answer by José Lorenzo was slightly more complete in my opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your business layer can be put anywhere under the `src` directory. For example you could have a folder called `src/Core` or `src/MyBusiness` or you could have multiple folders like `src/Command` `src/Handler`, it is up to you how you want to architecture your application other than serving a web request or accessing data in the database.

Classes put inside any folder inside `src` will be automatically loaded if given the right namespace.

```
// in src/MyBusiness/BusinessRules.php

namespace App\MyBusiness;
class BusinessRules
{
    ...
}
```

You can automatically load this class from another use the `use` keyword:

```
// In another file
use App\MyBusiness\BusinessRules;

...
$rules = new BusinessRules();
```

CakePHP does not make assumptions for you when it comes to this kind of objects as they usually are very specific to your application. It does offer a wide variety of tools that can help you build a better architecture more rapidly and with less code. For example using the `Event` system for Aspect Oriented Programming, the configuration traits for creating adaptable implementations or the `Collection` library for working with data using a functional approach.